# What happens when during manual commit specific offset fails but next offsets in sequence commits successfully?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am writing a kafka consumer using poll mechanism in which I am getting 100 messages per poll. After consuming messages, I commit an offset manually one by one. While committing an offset, sometimes I get an error for one of the message out off 100 messages. Rest offsets commit successfully.

```
Offsets
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,....100
```

Let's say offset 5 commit fails but excluding offset 5 all offsets committed successfully.

So, in this case, what happens to the commit failed offset? Since offset moves sequentially, will I get the commit failed offset in next poll?

My primary investigation shows it reads the failed offset in next poll. Need expertise view on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not required to commit each offset individually. And if you commit offset `X` it implies that all smaller offset are committed, too.

Comment: Please note, I am committing each offset manually intentionally. So, it's not required that if offset x is committed, then all smaller offsets are committed too.

Comment: Well. "I am committing each offset manually intentionally" -- this is not recommended, as it puts high load on the brokers. Also i,f offset X get's commits, it implies that all smaller offsets are committed, and you cannot prevent that. That is how Kafka works.

Comment: Let's say, we set auto commit to true and the message processing which we do post consuming message fails, then we won't be able to consume the same message again. It will be there as per retention policy but for this then we have to keep note of failed message offsets. This is what I feel about auto commit policy. What's your say ?

Comment: If processing fails, you can re-read a message by using `seek()`. Does this help? Also, I agree that you often don't want to use auto-commit. However, even if you use auto-commit, there is usually no need to commit every message.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax In one of my project, use-case is consume the data, do some operations and produce it to new topic. I would like to commit the offset manually after successfull operations to avoid any data loss and for this in coding I'm using (autoCommit: false) and (consumer.commitOffsets) for committing offset manually.
As you pointed we don't need to commit each offset bcz it will create load on brokers, so what will be the best approach i can follow to avoid any data loss? please advise

Comment: Well, you can just commit every X messages I guess?